# Linux or Unix(LF) data reading

Tags: root-access, linux, encryption

Listen, I found my s/o being shady. I’m talking I’ve found out hotel visit type shady stuff. I have embedded myself in everything they own email,phone,and other ways. I have found even more stuff but everytime I get actual 100% stone cold proof. It disappears. Poof. Android phones and Linux is why I have stumbled upon. I can’t access it. However, I have accessed marker files and its data to read. How do I turn this data into a readable form? Also how do I find root files on an android? Broken down as you would say to a newbie please.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are asking for. Please edit your question and make it clear what your situation is and what you are asking for.